# Maintaining history with --allow-unrelated-histories?

Tags: git, rebase

I have two repos `foo` and `bar`, **they have no common root** I would like to merge the two repos, maintaining both of their histories.

I **NEED** to maintain `foo`'s commit history.. I would like `bar`'s history to be rebased on top of `foo` as a discrete patches.

For example,

- repo `foo` has file `/baz` with commits `A`, `B`, `C`.
- repo `bar` has file `/baz` with commits, `D`, `E`.

I would like the resulting repo `foo` to have `/baz`'s commits sequenced as such: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`.

When `D` lands it should always be taken as correct and complete.

It seems the preferred method of joining two repos is `--allow-unrelated-histories` and merging, but I need to know how to maintain the histories after the merge.

Answer (score 3):

The good news is that you can get what you want: *History*, in a Git repository, is just the commits.

The commits are numbered.  The numbers are hash IDs, and these are unique to the *content* of each commit.  If the *content* of two commits, in two different Git repositories, exactly matches, so do their hash IDs.  If the content differs, so do their hash IDs.

A Git repository's history is the set of commits in its repository.  To retain the history you are calling "foo's commit history", you need to retain those exact commits, with their exact contents.  Fortunately, that's what you say you want to do here too:

> I would like `bar`'s history to be rebased on top of foo as a discrete patches.

No commit is *ever* a "discrete patch", so you must mean that you want to copy some or all parts of the commits from bar.

That is, we'll start with the commits out of repository `foo`.  We'll copy them *exactly as is* so that they *are* the same commits, with the same hash IDs, into our new combined repository.  Then, we will  take each commit out of repository `bar`, make changes to it once it's not *in* Git as a *commit*, and put the result back as a *new* commit in our combined repository.

The new commits, being different from any previous commit, will have their own new and unique hash IDs.  So only repository `foo`'s history is retained.

> When [the first commit from repo `bar`] lands it should always be taken as correct and complete.

Now we're starting to talk about what the contents of each commit will be, so now we look at the mechanics of *making* a commit.

#### The normal process

Normally, when we make a *new* commit, we do that by:

- Starting with a clone of some existing repository, or starting with some existing repository.  Either is fine since the *commits* get copied by cloning, so that a clone has the same hash IDs.  (The *branch names* don't get copied—the clone gets *its own* branch names—but branch names in Git don't matter, except in terms of *finding* commit hash IDs.)
- Extracting one of these commits: `git checkout name` or (Git 2.23 or later) `git switch name`.  This uses the name to find the hash ID of the commit.  Git then copies the *snapshot* part of the commit out to two places:

  - One copy goes into Git's index.  This is what Git will use to make the *next* commit snapshot.
  - The other copy goes into your working tree.  The files inside a commit are not useful for anything except as an archived snapshot: they're compressed, de-duplicated, and generally only readable by Git itself.  So they have to be un-archived and expanded into useful form.  *Git* does not need these files: your work-tree copy of each file is for *you*, because *you* need these files in this form.
- Now we work with the files, and maybe change some of them.  If we do change some of them, and want to make a new snapshot, we have to use `git add` to copy the updated files back into Git's index, booting out the old copy and replacing it with the updated file.  (Or, if the file is all-new, we don't boot anything out, we just add a new file.)
- Then we run `git commit`: Git makes a *new* commit with all-new metadata that Git constructs from your `user.name` and `user.email` setting and other information it has.  The *snapshot* of the new commit is from Git's index.  The overall *content* of the commit is the snapshot plus the metadata.

Having written out a new commit into the all-commits-and-other-Git-objects database, Git then stashes the new commit's new and unique hash ID into the *current branch name*, so that Git can find the new commit, using the current branch name.  The new commit is now frozen for all time: this hash ID is now used up and means *this* commit.

#### What you want instead

You will start by cloning the `foo` repository as a whole, so that you get all three of its commits, `A-B-C`.  Each of these three commits has a full snapshot of every file.  This is a normal everyday clone operation, working the usual way: copy all the commits and none of the branches, then create one new branch name matching the source repository's branch name, holding the same commit hash ID.

Next, you'll probably want to `git remote add` the `bar` repository, so that you can `git fetch` all of its commits: in this case, `D` and `E`.  These too are full snapshots of every file.

It is now up to you to decide how you want to take snapshot-and-metadata `D` out of your combined repository and make a new and different commit `D'` that has a snapshot and that links back to existing commit `C`.  You can retain as much of `D`'s metadata as you like, *except for the parent hash ID*.  Commit `D`, in repository `bar`, is the initial commit, so it says that there is *no parent*.  You need a commit `D'` that says *there is one parent and it is ______ (insert hash ID of commit `C` here)*.

Having made `D'` from `D`, you now need to make `E'` from `E`.  This is basically the same process.

You talk about wanting to retain one *file*, but each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file.  If you want to retain *every* file from commit `D`, completely ignoring the snapshot in commit `C`, this is easy, because commit `D` has, as *its* snapshot, the exact correct set of files.  You just re-use `D`'s snapshot when you make your `D'`.  If you only want to retain one *file* from `D`, it's still easy-ish, though it's just a tiny bit harder.

This repeats for commit `E`, and then, since there were just the two commits, you are now done.  Your combined repository has in it:

```
A--B--C   <-- foo/main
       \
        D'-E'   <-- main (HEAD)

D--E   <-- bar/main
```

(assuming the two input repositories have branches named `main` used to find their final commits).

You'll need to say whether you want the full snapshot from `D` as `D'`, or whether you want a single file, before we talk about ways to obtain the result.

#### If you want `D`'s snapshot in `D'` ...

If you want to keep the *entire snapshot* from commit `D` as the new commit `D'` snapshot, what we'll want is for the new commit `D'` to literally use that `tree` object (this is an internal detail of a commit that we wouldn't normally worry about, but it becomes a useful possibility here).

We also need to know what you want for `D'`'s *metadata:* for its author, committer, and date strings, and for its log message.  You can have Git copy those from `D` directly.

To do both of these, we will:

- use `git replace`, at least temporarily, to make a *graft*; then
- use `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` or similar to turn the graft permanent.

The way grafts—made with [`git replace` with the `--graft` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace)—work is to copy a commit except for its parent linkage:

> `--graft <commit> [<parent>...]`
> Create a graft commit. A new commit is created with the same
> content as <commit> except that its parents will be
> [<parent>...] instead of <commit>'s parents. A
> replacement ref is then created to replace <commit> with
> the newly created commit. Use `--convert-graft-file` to convert a
> `$GIT_DIR/info/grafts` file and use replace refs instead.

So, given:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD), foo/main

D--E   <-- bar/main
```

in your replacement-so-far repository, you can now run:

```
git replace --graft bar/main~1 main
```

Here the `<commit>` argument is `bar/main~1`.  This is the commit that is to be copied.  The `<parent>...` arguments are just `main`.  Git will resolve `bar/main~1` to a commit hash ID to find commit `D`, and will resolve `main` to find commit `C`.  It then makes a new commit—`D'`—whose *contents* are from commit `D` with one change: the snapshot is the same, and most of the metadata are the same, but the parent list is commit `C` (i.e., the one found by `main`).

Git then makes a very weird name—it's not a branch name; it's not a tag name; it's not a remote-tracking name; it lives in the `refs/replace/` [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) and has `D`'s raw hash ID as the rest of its name—that locates this new commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD), foo/main
       \
        D'  <-- refs/replace/<hash>

D--E   <-- bar/main
```

If we now run `git log bar/main`, Git:

- looks up commit `E` and displays it, then follows the parent link to `D`;
- goes to look up commit `D`, but sees that there is a `refs/replace/` for `D`, so immediately jumps over to `D'` instead, and displays that;
- moves back from `D` to `C` (there's no replacement for `C`) and displays `C`;
- moves back to `B` and displays it; and
- moves back to `A` and displays it.

This is how replacements work.  **There's one big drawback with replacement commits, and that is that `git clone` normally *does not* copy them.**  That might be OK!  If this repository is the *only* place you *ever* need this behavior, you can just about stop here.  This has some advantages because now commit `E`, in this repository, is literally the actual commit `E` from repository `bar`.  Should repository `bar` add new commits, you can just bring them into your repository and use them.

Right now, though, let's now move the name `main` to point to `E`:

```
git reset --hard bar/main
```

or (this should work but I have not tried it):

```
git merge --ff-only bar/main
```

The result is:

```
A--B--C   <-- foo/main
       \
        D'  <-- refs/replace/<hash>

D--E   <-- main (HEAD), bar/main
```

If this drawback about grafts not getting cloned *isn't* OK—and/or if you never intend to contact repository `bar` again—you can now "cement the replacement".  To do that, you must have Git re-copy each commit in place.  More precisely, we only need to recopy commits `D` and `E`, with the replacement being done during the re-copying, but it's *easiest* to re-copy all commits, with `git filter-branch`.

#### Using filter-branch or filter-repo

There is one big problem with filter-branch: it's being retired.  It still exists in Git, and it still works (or should work), but it is no longer supported.  Instead, [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) is recommended now—but it's not included with Git distributions yet.  Both have the same fundamental principles of operation though.

Since a repository is nothing more than a collection of commits and other internal Git objects, plus a collection of *names* by which we *find* the commits and other objects, we can have a program:

- walk some or all commits, either literally or virtually extracting them (snapshot and/or metadata) to a temporary area;
- apply some filter(s) to the snapshot and/or metadata; and
- construct a *new* commit from the filtered result.

If the new commit is absolutely, completely, 100% identical, bit-for-bit, to the original commit, it gets the same hash-ID number.  If it's different, it gets a different number.

By walking the commits from oldest to newest,<sup>1</sup> keeping a map—*old hash ID _____ = new hash ID _____*—we can make arbitrary changes to the entire repository.  Any commit that's not changed at all, including no changes to its parentage, retains its hash ID.  Any commit that *is* changed—as in, different snapshot or different history (parent linkage)—gets a new number.

Once we've finished the operation over all the commits to be operated-on, we can then adjust some or all of the *names*, so that instead of finding the old commits, they find the new ones.

Because you'll have to pick one of filter-branch or filter-repo, this answer does not have a specific recipe for either one—but I'll note here that we don't actually intend to make any *specific* change to anything about any commit.  All we want is for the filter operation to *obey the graft*.  That is, when making a copy of commit `D`, filter-branch or filter-repo should look up the replacement `D'` instead of using the original `D`.

When the filter operation does this, here's the result:

- To copy `A`, we grab all the bits from `A` and make no changes.  The result gets written back.  It's 100% bit-for-bit identical *to* `A`, so it is still `A`.
- To copy `B`, we grab all the bits from `B` and make no changes except to replace the parent of `B` with the new copy of `A`.  That's still `A`!  So the copy of `B` is 100% bit-for-bit identical, and hence *is* `B`.
- To copy `C`, we grab all its bits and ... well, this is just like `B`: the copy of `C` *is* `C`.
- To copy `D`, we grab all the bits of ... no, wait, there's a replacement!  We grab all the bits of `D'`.  We replace `D'`'s parent `C` with the copy, which is still `C`.  So writing this back, we get `D'`.  That means the copy of `D` *is* `D'`.
- To copy `E`, we grab all the bits of `E`, but replace `E's parent (`D`) with its copy (`D'`).  This means that the copy of` E`is not bit-for-bit identical.  Instead, it's`E'`, a copy of` E`that leads back to`D`.

Hence after the copy process (but before adjusting branch names), we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- foo/main
       \
        D'  <-- refs/replace/<hash>
         \
          E'

D--E   <-- bar/main, main (HEAD)
```

Now we go in and change some set of branch names.  The only actual branch name here is `main`.  We replace the hash ID in `main` with its copy, i.e., change from pointing to `E`, to pointing to `E` instead:

```
A--B--C   <-- foo/main
       \
        D'  <-- refs/replace/<hash>
         \
          E'  <-- main (HEAD)

D--E   <-- bar/main
```

We can now delete the `refs/replace/` *name* (which is how clones operate: they fail to copy the name, which is like deleting it) since we never plan to follow `bar/main` from `E` to `D`.  If we also delete the `bar/main` name, that leaves us with original commits `D-E` un-findable, and a repository that looks like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- foo/main
       \
        D'-E'  <-- main (HEAD)
```

which is what we wanted.

---

<sup>1</sup>It's worth noting here that both filter commands still use Git's backwards method of *finding* commits.  That is, while filter-branch and filter-repo need to copy commits "forwards", from `A` onward, they *find* the commits "backwards" first.  We start at commit `E`, then move back to `D`—and jump to the grafted replacement—and move back to `C`, then `B`, then `A`.  Having collected the list of commit hash IDs, Git now just reverses the order.  (Technically it collects the list in a *topological sort* order, then reverses from there.)

---

#### If you need to retain *all* the commit hashes ...

You mention in your own answer that `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` works for what you want.  This is true because `git log` with a file name—you don't need `--follow` here, just the file name—defaults to using *history simplification* when tracking down how some file(s) became the way they are in the final commit.

Let's just draw the *effect* of merging with the `--allow-unrelated-histories` flag.  We start with a combining repository as before:

```
A--B--C   <-- foo/main

D--E   <-- main (HEAD), bar/main
```

Note, however, that this time I have chosen commit `E` to be our `main`—perhaps via `git reset --hard E`.  That's for the `-s ours` below.  If we don't need `-s ours`, we can pick either tip commit, but we're going to have to make sure that the merge commit's copy of that one particular file is the copy from commit `E`.

We now just run `git merge` with the flag that says that it should merge anyway.  We can add `-s ours` to make Git *completely ignore* all files in the snapshot in `C`, which is pretty convenient.  Git will then add one new *merge commit*, which I will draw as `M` for merge, that links back to both commits `E` *and* `C`.  The first parent of `M` will be `E`, and the second will be `C`, so I'm going to flip the lines over as well:<sup>2</sup>

```
D-----E   <-- bar/main
       \
        M   <-- main (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- foo/main
```

When using this kind of operation, note that the original commits are completely untouched.  They therefore retain their original hash IDs and hence *are* the original history.

If this kind of merge is acceptable, it's usually the best way to deal with this.  It's not at all the same as what you described, though: the history does not appear to start at `E` and work back to `A`, the way Git usually does with linear history.  Instead, the history now starts at `M`, and immediately diverges into both `E` *and* `C`.  When using `git log` with no options, you'll see  both lines of history.  When using `git log -- filename`, however, you'll see only the line of history that explains the *outcome:* the version of the file that appears in commit `M`.  So if the copy of the named file in `M` matches that in `E`, but not that in `C`, `git log` will follow the line from `M` back to `E`.  That leaves Git with only one remaining commit to visit: `D`.

The last option you have here is the one we already described above, using `git replace`.  We can use this to make Git "avert its eyes" from any one particular commit, using as a substitute a commit made by `git replace`.  A *graft* commit re-uses the snapshot, but makes arbitrary changes to the *parents*.

---

<sup>2</sup>The first vs second parent at a merge is mostly useful with `git log --first-parent`, which—when hitting a merge—pretends that there is no *second* parent.  In this case, for instance, it completely ignores commit `C`.

Comment: “You need a commit D' that says there is one parent and it is ______ (insert hash ID of commit C here).” That’s right but you forgot to say how to obtain that?

Comment: When you say, "It is now up to you to decide how you want to take snapshot-and-metadata D out of your combined repository and make a new and different commit D' that has a snapshot and that links back to existing commit C." That's exactly what the question is... You wrote so much without actually telling me how to do this (I wrote up the situation pretty well).

Comment: To make more sense of it, look bellow I have *exactly* what I want if I use `--follow`. I just want it to work like that without having to `--follow`.

Comment: @matt: if we use `git replace --graft` followed by a no-op filter-branch or filter-repo, we'll just use the branch name or the remote-tracking name. If we need something fancier (because we don't want the exact trees from D and E) we'll need, well, something fancier.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: sorry, sometimes we must take breaks away from the computer. :-) If you want the *tree* from `D`—all the files exactly as they appear in `D`—to be in `D'`, we'll use `git replace` (for an en-masse many-commit operation) or perhaps just `git commit-tree` (to copy two commits).

Comment: OK, it's updated now with several alternatives. One thing: You keep mentioning what you want for the file named `baz` in the two streams of commits, but you never mentioned what you want to see with *all the other files* in the two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `--allow-unrelated-history` maintains the history of both files which can be accessed with the `--follow` command on `git log`

```
--follow
  Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single file)
```

I'd still like to know how to do this without needing to use `--follow`, but that's probably good enough.